# How to create script for roblox studio? (footbal game)

Tags: lua, roblox

How to create a script in which when you press a key, for example "e", shoot the soccer ball. If it's not difficult for you, can you write how to make the animation of raising the leg on impact?)

Vector3 dont work.(

Comment: Heyo, when you ask a question on StackOverflow, the expectation is that you first try to solve it yourself, and then you share your code, and explain the specific problem you are having. Please edit your question to include the code that isn't working and any error messages you're getting.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to use the UserInputService. First create a LocalScript in StarterPlayerScripts, which is in the StarterPlayer folder visible to the explorer. And type this.

```
local UserInputService = game.UserInputService 

function Press()
if UserInputService.KeyCode = Enum.KeyCode.E then
  —type in the things you want it to do after clicking E
    end
end

UserInputService.InputBegin:Connect(Press)
```

Comment: Can this help for you to do something when you pressed the key E?

Comment: You should explain the code. The code without any explanation does not improve the knowledge/skills of the readers, and they would likely make that mistake again.